# How to include transitive dependencies when using ProjectRef in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I would like to reference a project from another sbt project without creating an aggregate ("root") project.

I have two projects that depend on some shared code, however they are independent enough so that putting them under an aggregate ("root") project does not really makes sense (i.e. I am never going to build both projects at the same time and I would like them to be in separate git repositories, however I will be updating the shared code while working on either of them).

My current solution is as follows:

```
lazy val core = ProjectRef(file("../Core"), "core")

lazy val console = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(core)
```

This worked until I had to add a library dependency to the "core" project, and now I can't build the "console" project. It fails with the following message:

```
[error] missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'Settings.class'.
[error] Could not access term typesafe in package com,
[error] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
[error] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'Settings.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.
```

It is obviously referring to the missing "com.typesafe.config" library that core depends on.

Is there any way to fix this so that the console project is compiled with dependencies of core?